# Restoring NSUserActivity

Tags: swift, nsuseractivity

I am working with MacCatalyst and I would like to restore the previous content of windows after reopening the app. I found an example project (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/restoring_your_app_s_state). I adopted the `stateRestorationActivity(for scene: UIScene)` method, however, according to the example project, when I want to configure a scene in the `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` method based on the `session.stateRestorationActivity`, the variable is always nil. Here's my code:

In SceneDelegate:

```
func stateRestorationActivity(for scene: UIScene) -> NSUserActivity? {
    return scene.userActivity
}



func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
        titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
        titlebar.toolbarStyle = .unified
    }
    #endif
    
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene

    let contentViewController = ContentViewController()
            
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contentViewController)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first ?? session.stateRestorationActivity {
        if !configure(window: window, with: userActivity) {
            print("Failed to restore from \(userActivity)")
        }
    } else {
        if !configure(window: window, with: ContentType.Inbox.openDetailUserActivity) {
            
        }
    }
            
}
```

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}


// MARK: - UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    
    var configurationName: String!
    
    switch options.userActivities.first?.activityType {
    case .UserActivity.SystemActivityType, .UserActivity.TagActivityType, .UserActivity.ProjectActivityType:
        configurationName = "Detail Configuration"
    default:
        configurationName = "Default Configuration"
    }
    
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: configurationName, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)

}
```

I registred different configurations of `UISceneSessions` in the info plist.

Comment: I don't think you need the "secure application state" methods in your `AppDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to assign a `NSUserActivity` to the correct `UIWindowScene` property with your view controller's `viewWillAppear` method, then in the `viewWillDisappear` assign `nil` to that property.

Make sure to assign it to the `UIViewController` that is the `rootViewController` for the `UIWindow` being shown. Meaning, if you have a `UINavigationController` as the parent, use `navigationController?.view.window?.windowScene?.userActivity`.

A [code example](https://darjeelingsteve.com/articles/Advanced-Multi-window-UIs-on-iPadOS-with-Drag-and-Drop-and-State-Restoration.html) is available, not mine, but a helpful one.

It seems like the state restoration subsystem takes the user activity from any view controllers of active scenes and stores the state from it, which makes sense.

Also, make sure to store your information in `NSUserActivity.userInfo`.

More details [available](https://jotnow.com/JN-23j) on my blog as well.